# Django: Why am I getting a 400 bad request error?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am developing a web application on django + react And I needed to make a request in which I pass a list
with ids, but I have a '"POST /api/questions/ HTTP/1.1" 400 39'

models.py

```
class TestQuestionBlok(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='questionsImages/')
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(TestAnswers)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

views.py

```
questions = []
class TestQuestionList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        global questions
        romms = TestQuestionBlok.objects.filter(id__in=questions)
        serializer = TestQuestionSerializers(romms, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        global questions
        serializer1 = TestQuestionSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer1.is_valid():
            print(serializer1.data['answers'])
            return Response(serializer1.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer1.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class TestQuestionSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TestQuestionBlok
        fields = ('answers', )
```

Testpage.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "../styles/Testpage.css"

function Testpage() {
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"


    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/',
          data: {
            answers: [1, 3]
          }
        })
    }, [])

   return (
        <div>
            a
        </div>
    );
}

export default Testpage;
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please add your TestQuestionBlok model too, your serializer only has an `answers` field but you are passing `question: [1, 3]` in your data. You also aren't doing anything with the validated data in your view?

Comment: @IainShelvington I added models.py

Comment: Your model has a required `image` field which you don't include in your serializer or data and a required `question` field which you don't include in your serializer or data either. How are you expecting to get a valid instance from that data?

Comment: @IainShelvington from the frontend, the post function receives the id of those responses that need to be passed to the get function, and not to find the object

Comment: It's really not clear what you are attempting, POST requests are generally used for submitting data to be saved in the system but you seem to be using it for something else. Please make it clear in your question __why__ you are submitting that data and what you want to __use__ that data for. Your GET api is trying to access some global `questions` variable??

Comment: @IainSHelvington I use the post in this code to pass the id that the frontend sends to the post function to the get function, I do this so that the get function understands what needs to be returned

Comment: Why not just send that data in the GET request and filter the data there? Using global variables is not a good idea. You are not using serializers correctly since you are not actually passing serlialized objects. POSTing data to later use in a GET request doesn't make any sense

Comment: @IainShelvington With `questions = []`

I am passing information between the post function and the get function

Comment: @IainShelvington in Get functions, the data to be sent is not known

Comment: Using a global variable like that is a terrible design for a lot of reasons: what if your app restarts, what if you have multiple clients, what if you have multiple workers? Your GET requests should contain the appropriate data to retrieve the required result - pass the answers data as GET data

Comment: @IainShelvington I think about such consequences, but I have no other options how to explain the get function that it should return

Comment: @IainShelvington Please, if you have other applications, please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `answers` field should defined as the list of `id`.

```
class TestQuestionSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer_ids = serializers.ListField(child = serializers.IntegerField(), write_only = True):

    class Meta:
        model = TestQuestionBlok
        fields = ('answers', )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'answers': { 'read_only': True }
        }
```

And in frontend, you need to upload with the key `answer_ids`.

```
...
useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/',
      data: {
        answer_ids: [1, 3]  # here I changed the field name
      }
    })
}, [])
...
```

Then the 400 error will not occur.
And of course, there are other places you need to add. `Image` and `question` field should be added in the serializer.